# Correctly eager loading empty array being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, eager-loading

I have a many-to-one relationship `images` on my `vehicle` model. I have set up a query similar to `Vehicle.includes(:images).find(ids)` Several, correctly, have an empty array loaded since these `vehicles` have no images. However, it goes back to the Mongo server, trying to find out if there are any images. The identity map is enabled and all that jazz. Eager loading seems to work for non-empty arrays.

How would I signal to Mongoid that the empty array is correct and not to try and load them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did find a good way to resolve this. It seems the identity map will not store empty arrays and when I manually stuffed an empty array into the IdentityMap, it worked as expected.

Here is our work around in case someone else has this question:

We made sure there was an index on `vehicle_id` in the `image` model, then loaded all the images in a separate query and stuck them into the relevant vehicle objects. We never load more than 25 vehicles at once through this method, so we went from 26 queries to 2.

Might not be performant if loading an appreciable amount of elements in memory.